# Implement Deserialize for a structure with Box

Tags: rust, deserialization, serde, serde-json

A struct containing Box as member variable:

```rust
type Item = dyn Fn() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>>;
struct Inner {
    pub data: Box<Item>,
}

// a function, like the type: Item
fn parse() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>> {
    println!("parse called");
    Ok(())
}
```

now comes the problem that custom implement a deserialize for struct `Inner` to de-serialize:

```
let s = r#"{"data": "parse"}"#;
```

into struct Inner:

```
{
    data: Box::new(parse)
}
```

I know `serde` don't implement deserialize for `Box<T>`, and have to implement Deserialize manually, here is my code followed the example given by [docmentaion](https://serde.rs/deserialize-struct.html):

```rust
use serde::de::{self, Deserialize, Deserializer, MapAccess, Visitor};
use std::fmt;

type Item = dyn Fn() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>>;
struct Inner {
    pub data: Box<Item>,
}

fn parse() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>> {
    println!("parse called");
    Ok(())
}

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for Inner {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        enum Field {
            Data,
        };

        impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for Field {
            fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Field, D::Error>
            where
                D: Deserializer<'de>,
            {
                struct FieldVisitor;

                impl<'de> Visitor<'de> for FieldVisitor {
                    type Value = Field;

                    fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
                        formatter.write_str("`data` only")
                    }

                    fn visit_str<E>(self, value: &str) -> Result<Field, E>
                    where
                        E: de::Error,
                    {
                        match value {
                            "data" => Ok(Field::Data),
                            _ => Err(de::Error::unknown_field(value, FIELDS)),
                        }
                    }
                }

                deserializer.deserialize_identifier(FieldVisitor)
            }
        }

        struct InnerVisitor;

        impl<'de> Visitor<'de> for InnerVisitor {
            type Value = Inner;

            fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
                formatter.write_str("struct Inner")
            }

            fn visit_map<V>(self, mut map: V) -> Result<Inner, V::Error>
            where
                V: MapAccess<'de>,
            {
                let mut data = None;
                while let Some(key) = map.next_key()? {
                    match key {
                        Field::Data => {
                            if data.is_some() {
                                return Err(de::Error::duplicate_field("data"));
                            }
                            data = Some(map.next_value()?);
                        }
                    }
                }
                let data = data.ok_or_else(|| de::Error::missing_field("data"))?;
                //
                // do something on the `data` and finally return a Item-like function  (***)
                //
                Ok(Inner {
                    data: Box::new(parse),
                }) // (***)
            }
        }

        const FIELDS: &'static [&'static str] = &["data"];
        deserializer.deserialize_struct("Inner", FIELDS, InnerVisitor)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = r#"{"data": "parse"}"#;
    let inner: Inner = serde_json::from_str(s).unwrap();
}
```

However, when I run these code it get error:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
warning: unused variable: `inner`
  --> src/main.rs:93:9
   |
93 |     let inner: Inner = serde_json::from_str(s).unwrap();
   |         ^^^^^ help: if this is intentional, prefix it with an underscore: `_inner`
   |
   = note: `#[warn(unused_variables)]` on by default

warning: unused variable: `data`
  --> src/main.rs:76:21
   |
76 |                 let data = data.ok_or_else(|| de::Error::missing_field("data"))?;
   |                     ^^^^ help: if this is intentional, prefix it with an underscore: `_data`

warning: 2 warnings emitted

    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 1.12s
     Running `target/debug/playground`
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error("invalid type: string \"parse\", expected unit", line: 1, column: 16)', src/main.rs:93:48
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Roughly, I guess the problem lies in `(***)` of the block, but got no clue how to tackle it. How to correctly implement `Deserialize` for my use case?

Comment: for next time don't forget to include the use lines and all required code in the final MCVE, losing time playing Cluedo is not very useful to answer a question :p

Comment: oh my bad and appreciate that,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The warning gives you a hint: you didn't use data, so Rust doesn't care what type is inside the Option. Actually I'm surprise it's compiling. Rust assumes you expect `()`, because of serdes default type, while you expect a `String`. Your data is simply not consumed so just do:

```rust
let mut data: Option<&str> = None;
```

Also, I advice to replace all your `Field` implementation with:

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(field_identifier, rename_all = "lowercase")]
enum Field {
    Data,
}
```

(This stack overflows for unknown reason on [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8c68618fccebcb208995a5faa67b2533) but I expect this is an issue with the playground)

---

Also, you could just use [deserialize_with](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#deserialize_with):

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer};

type Item = dyn Fn() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>>;
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Inner {
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "deserialize_data")]
    pub data: Box<Item>,
}

fn deserialize_data<'de, D>(d: D) -> Result<Box<Item>, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    let data = <&str>::deserialize(d)?;
    println!("{}", data);
    Ok(Box::new(parse))
}

fn parse() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>> {
    println!("parse called");
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    let s = r#"{"data": "parse"}"#;
    let inner: Inner = serde_json::from_str(s).unwrap();
}
```

This is way better because the implementation by serde macro could do a lot better code than a naïve implementation.

Answer (score 3):

A similar trick to Stargateurs is to use `#[serde(from = "FromType")]` on the `Inner` class. This lets you go via an intermediary struct by implementing the `From` trait.

```
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct InnerRepr {
    pub data: String,
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(from = "InnerRepr")]
struct Inner {
    pub data: Box<Item>,
}

impl From<InnerRepr> for Inner {
  fn from(repr: InnerRepr) -> Inner {
    Inner{ data: Box::new(parse) }
  }
}
```